# How to extract a conditional range from ordered composite boost::multi_index

Tags: boost-multi-index

In the following simplified example:

```
struct SalesRecord
{
    time_t date;
    std::string department;
    int sales_person_id;

    int num_sales;
    int total_num_sales;
};

typedef multi_index_container
    <
        SalesRecPtr,
        indexed_by
        <
            ordered_unique // 0
            <
                composite_key
                <
                    SalesRecPtr,
                    member <SalesRecord, time_t,      &SalesRecord::date>,
                    member <SalesRecord, std::string, &SalesRecord::department>,
                    member <SalesRecord, int,         &SalesRecord::sales_person_id>
                >,
                composite_key_compare
                <
                    std::greater<time_t>,
                    std::less<std::string>,
                    std::less<int>
                >
            >,
            ordered_unique // 1
            <
                composite_key
                <
                    SalesRecPtr,
                    member <SalesRecord, std::string, &SalesRecord::department>,
                    member <SalesRecord, int,         &SalesRecord::sales_person_id>,
                    member <SalesRecord, time_t,      &SalesRecord::date>
                >,
                composite_key_compare
                <
                    std::less<std::string>,
                    std::less<int>,
                    std::greater<time_t> // could also be std::less  here
                >
            >
        >
    > SALES_RECORDS;
```

This SALES_RECORDS Collection may contain sale records by person and department who made **at least** one sale a day. A person "A" from department "Dep1" could have sales on date 1, 3, 4, 5, 20;

**Q. How to acquire a range from this collection that finds all records for this person ("A"), department ("Dep1") after day 4?**
This could be used to update total number of sales after correcting a number of sales on a particular date.
Currently, I am retrieving an equal_range for a person and iterate to the date needed which adds undesirable linear complexity to my searches.

Answer (score 0):

```
tm     t{0,0,0,4,2,121,4}; // Mar 4, 2021
time_t tt=mktime(&t);
int    person_id=5;

auto first=sales_records.get<1>().lower_bound(std::make_tuple("Dep1",person_id)),
     last =sales_records.get<1>().lower_bound(std::make_tuple("Dep1",person_id,tt));
```

**Update:** The same thing can be done with `range` (C++14 used in the example):

```
auto p=sales_records.get<1>().range(
    [cmp=sales_records.get<1>().key_comp(),from=std::make_tuple("Dep1",person_id)   ]
    (const auto& x){return !cmp(x,from);},
    [cmp=sales_records.get<1>().key_comp(),to  =std::make_tuple("Dep1",person_id,tt)]
    (const auto& x){return cmp(x,to);});
```

but the resulting code is really much more cumbersome than the `range`-less alternative.

Comment: Thank you! 
Originally I thought there is a way to do it using "sales_records.get<1>().range ()".

Comment: `range` can also be used, updated answer.